# If $z$ revolves around $a$ why $f(z)=\sqrt{z-a}$ revolves round origin

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the complex function
$$
f(z)=\sqrt{z-a}
$$
if z revolves around $a$  why $f(z)$ evolves round origin.

Comment: note that you cannot define $\sqrt{z-a}$ to get a continuous function on a full disk containing $a$. so you should make clear exactly what you mean by $\sqrt{z-a}$ and where it is defined

Answer (score 1):

"$z$ revolves around $a$" could mean for example that $z$ goes around $a$ in a circle of radius $r$, thus $z = r e^{i \phi} + a$.

Then $\sqrt{z - a} = \sqrt{r} e^{i \phi / 2}$ revolves around $0$ in a circle of radius $\sqrt{r}$.

More generally, you could have $r(\phi)$ there for some nonnegative function $r$ of $\phi$.